# Multichannel signal processing: Thread architecture

Tags: multithreading, architecture, queue, signal-processing

I question my initial thoughts on a multi channel signal processing architecture.

It's pretty straight forward: There is a source and a sink with X channels and different processing steps (grouped), that have to be applied to every channel (with the same settings and in the same order).

In the end, all channels have to be synchronized again at the sink.

For a multithreaded multichannel architecture, I came up with two possible solutions:

[image: Options of thread grouping: channelwise vs processwise]

1. **Channelwise grouping**:

   - processing is completely split for every channel
   - processing groups are connected with one queue for every channel
   - **pros**:

     - less blocking of threads due to synchronization of channels
     - no data structure for channel merging necessary
   - **cons**:

     - more queues
2. **Processwise grouping**:

   - channels are merged before every processing group
   - processing groups are connected with only one queue for all channels
   - **pros**:

     - less queues
     - channels are synchronized over all processing groups
   - **cons**:

     - merging and splitting necessary
     - data structure for merging all channels necessary

What are your opinions on those solutions? Did I forget pros / cons? Which solution is more practial? Are there are more appropiate solution?

Comment: Hi, opinion-based questions like this are off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please check the [help] for info on what kinds of questions you should ask here.

Comment: @TylerH I don't think that it's opinion based question, because the question is about the more correct way to use. It's about system running time and performance, and not about theoretical things.

Comment: @KorelK The 'correct way' is an opinion when multiple ways work; OP asks multiple opinion questions, *including* literally asking for our opinions on it. Even your answer says "it depends" and doesn't provide a concrete objective 'correct' way.

Answer (score 2):

Look, it's true that in the second way you have less queues, but you still store the same amount of data, and you do more actions on it, that cost you in processing time. For the architecture of the queues you can simply use an array of queues, and in the end of the data's processing from all of the channels you can merge them and store the results or do whatever you want with them.

But it's depend on what kind of system you got- Real Time, that every split/merge can cost you an expensive time, or Single shot of receiving and then you don't have to pay so much attention to processing time. If it is a single shot of receiving system- you can do whatever will be easier for you- programming time is also important.

I hope it's help you with your decision.